# Showing convergence of $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1) z^j$ and finding its sum with $|z|<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I found two ways to find the sum of the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1) z^j$, one using derivatives and one using products. However, some steps I take I'm not quite sure about, and would appreciate some feedback or explanation.

---

***Excuse my misuse of the capital N and n, in the calculations I mean N when I say n.***

***Proof 1:***

*In this proof I'm not sure if I can say that* $\frac{z^{n+1}((n_1)z-n-2)}{(z-1)^2} \to0$ *as* $n\to\infty$.

Let $S'_N$ be the the partial sum of the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1) z^j$. 
Then $S'_N = \sum_{j=0}^{N}(j+1) z^n$ and $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N}z^{n+1} = z\sum_{n=0}^{N} z^n = z(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{z^{n+1}}{1-z})$ such that $\frac{dS_N}{dz}=S'_N$.

By then taking its derivative again, we find $S'_N = \frac{z^{n+1}((n_1)z-n-2)+1}{(z-1)^2} = \frac{z^{n+1}((n_1)z-n-2)}{(z-1)^2} + \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$ .

We know that if $|z|<1$, $z^{n+1}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ so that $\frac{z^{n+1}((n_1)z-n-2)}{(z-1)^2} \to0$ as $n\to\infty$ which means $S'_N\to\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$ as $n\to\infty$, thus we will find that: $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1) z^j = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$. $\tag*{$\Box$}$

---

***Proof 2:***

*In this proof I'm not sure if I can say that* $\frac{(N+1)z^{N+1}}{1-z}\to0$ *as* $n\to\infty$.

Let $S_N$ be the partial sum of the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1) z^j$.

$S_N = 1+2z+3z^2+...+(N+1)z^N \iff zS_N = z+2z^2+3z^3+...+(N+1)z^{N+1} \iff$
$S_N-zS_N=S_N(1-z)=1+z+z^2+z^3...+(N+1)z^{N+1} = 
\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}+(N+1)z^{N+1}\iff$
$S_N=\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{(N+1)z^{N+1}}{1-z}$

We know that if $|z|<1$, $z^{n+1}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ and that $\frac{(N+1)z^{N+1}}{1-z}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ too, so that $S_N\to\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ as $n\to\infty$, thus we will find that: $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1) z^j = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$. $\tag*{$\Box$}$

Comment: I don't really follow proof 1. Proof 2 looks excellent.

Comment: What I do in proof 1, is finding the antiderivative of the partial sum, so I can write it out and derive it again so you get the original partial sum, as you cannot derive the limit. Then taking the limit of  the found partial sum of series, I conclude that it converges to that value.

Answer (score 1):

For $|z|<1$ the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^j$ converges absolutely. An easy calculation with Cauchy product gives

$$(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^j)\cdot(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^j)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (j+1)z^j $$

for $|z|<1.$